# Is there a python wrapper to look for a certificate in the Mac OS Keychain?

Tags: python, macos, cryptography, keychain

I need to create a python app that searches for a particular "certificate" stored in the Mac OS keychain so that I can get the public (or private) key to do encryption/decryption.  But, I am unable to find an already existing python project that would do this.  Is there one that I just have not found yet?

The [keyring](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/) project looked very promising.  But, it does not have any code for accessing "certificates" in the Mac OS keychain.

At a minimum, I know that I would need to implement a call into the [SecItemCopyMatching](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1398306-secitemcopymatching) API within the security library.  But, the arguments to the SecItemCopyMatching seem to be complex that I'm not sure what the equivalent python type it would be.  What would a CFDictionary look like in python?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take a look at this gist:

https://gist.github.com/gcollazo/9434580

You should be able to adapt that to working with certs:
https://ss64.com/osx/security-find-cert.html
https://ss64.com/osx/security-find-id.html